# How to implement a pannini projection in opengl?

Tags: opengl, mathematics, geometry, projection, vertex-shader

I have read about the pannini projection, which involves (I think) projecting a scene onto a cyclinder instead of a rectangle.

How can I implement this projection in a vertex shader?

Blinky is using lenses and globes, but I don't think it's what I am looking for. The lua script for the pannini projection is not commented https://github.com/shaunlebron/blinky/blob/master/game/lua-scripts/lenses/panini.lua

As explained on [The Pannini Projection](https://web.archive.org/web/20210518115947/http://tksharpless.net/vedutismo/Pannini/), it works (if I understand it well), by projecting geometry on a cylinder, and then unrolling that cylinder on screen.

[image: Diagram illustrating Pannini projection from a floor map]

Comment: If you did ray tracing, you'd just need to shoot each ray in a direction determined by the cylindrical frustum.

Comment: Honestly I thought this had to do with projecting a bread asset somehow. :D